# Single echo from array on controller

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

I am Using codeigniter here is my problem

```
Array
(
    [Name] => My Name
    [mobile] => +1xxxxxxxx
    [amount] => 995
)
```

I want to echo only Name on Controller.

I already try it but not working..

```
foreach($User as $row){
    echo $row->["1"];
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value "1" does not correspond to any key in the array.

If you want to echo the second element of a zero-indexed array, use the integer 1 (notice the lack of double quotes):

```
echo $row[1];
```

If you want to echo an array element by referencing the name of the key, specify the key name in quotes (single or double):

```
echo $row["Name"];
```

Answer (score 0):

you can extract the data with this method:

```
foreach($User as $row){ 
    echo $row['Name']; 
}
```

Marco